# How can I programmatically read out which speech recognition is selected in Android?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I would like to read out the selected speech recognition in the phone.

By default, the Google Voice Search is installed and selected.

Some devices also installed the Vlingo speech recognition.

How can I programmatically read out which speech recognition is selected?

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Lets get you started. You can follow this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/ And if you get stuck at some point with exception or some issue. We are here to help. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer ;) I've done everything and works fine. Now I need to know which speech recognition is selected. Can someone give me an example code or a link?

Comment: @Abhilasha He is talking about *speech recognition*, not *text-to-speech*. I'm wondering if you even read the question..

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't find the solution to this, you need to do the following:

```
final List<ResolveInfo> services = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(
        new Intent(RecognitionService.SERVICE_INTERFACE), 0);

String packageName = "";
String serviceName = "";

for (final ResolveInfo info : services) {

    packageName = info.serviceInfo.packageName;
    serviceName = info.serviceInfo.name;

    if (packageName != null && serviceName != null) {
    // Do something with the output here
    }
}
```

This is the adaptation I used [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15415208/1256219).