# How to programmatically override "Google Voice Search" over "Samsung powered by Vlingo"?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Some devices (like Samsung Galaxy S3) come pre-installed with [*Samsung powered by Vlingo*](http://www.electricpig.co.uk/2012/06/01/why-every-samsung-galaxy-s3-review-has-missed-the-point-about-s-voice/index.html) instead of [*Google Voice Search*](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.voicesearch).

In my app, I would like to programmatically override which speech **recognition** engine to use, so that Google Voice Search is always used by my app.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to tell which speech **recognition** engines are **installed**? (If so, how?)
2. Is there a way to tell which speech **recognition** engine is **selected** in the user settings? (If so, how?)
3. Is there a programmatic way to **override** user's selection, so that my app *always* invokes [Google Voice Search](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.voicesearch)? (if so , how?)

Help will be appreciated

Comment: Looks like I'm not the only one looking for a solution. [This one](http://www.android.net/forum/introductions-site-assistance/76895-replace-vlingo-back-google-voice-search.html) to no avail. But [this one](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s2-international/540153-finally-remove-vlingo-voice-command-without-root-ics-only.html) seems to have succeeded uninstalling as a user. Still, I prefer a way to programmatically achieve what I want without uninstalling *"Samsung powered by Vlingo"*.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Samsung's solution is already programmatically overriding yours :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to all your questions is "yes".

[createSpeechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html#createSpeechRecognizer%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.ComponentName%29) can be given the package name of the recognizer to use. So if you know the package name then you can override the default.

To detect the available services, use:

```
List<ResolveInfo> services =
    getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(
        new Intent(RecognitionService.SERVICE_INTERFACE), 0);
```

For more details study the source code of [Babble](https://github.com/Kaljurand/babble). I don't know if this is the best way to do it (any feedback is welcome) but it has worked on my devices. (Babble in general assumes Android 4+, but the speech recognizer detection part might also work on earlier versions.)